# Make buffer unreachable

Tags: python

This may be a silly question, but how can I make a buffer unreachable? I have enabled live-py-mode. Every time I try to edit my python file it evaluates the code, which is a well and good but it's a little annoying how it switches focus from the source file to the eval result. Is there a way I can prevent changing focus from source to result?

Comment: Maybe this description is clear to a Python user of Emacs; I can't say. To me (not such a user) it's not clear. If you think it might be unclear to others, consider providing a step-by-step recipe to demonstrate the problem, starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:*  In hindsight, I think I've answered a somewhat different question, and that your actual question probably requires direct knowledge of `live-py-mode` (which I don't have).  I would suspect that if the window in question is being *selected* and that doing so makes no sense, then this is probably a `live-py-mode` bug to be raised with its author?

The following answer was aimed at preventing a particular window from being displayed at all...

---

You can use the `display-buffer-no-window` action with `display-buffer-alist`, but you need to know how to identify the buffer.

Here I have assumed the buffer is always named `*py-live-eval*`, and have specified a regexp matching that.

```el
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             (cons "^\\*py-live-eval\\*$"
                   (cons 'display-buffer-no-window
                         '((allow-no-window . t)))))
```